# VB.Net (2008) How can I make the letters as PasswordChar "*" while retaining the first letter as the original?

Tags: vb.net

I tried using this code

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    If TextBox2.TextLength > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = TextBox2.TextLength - 1 To 1 Step -1
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace(TextBox2.Text.Substring(i, 1), "*")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

But it didn't work out

I'm using textbox and my desired output is: `P*******` which is PASSWORD

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you mean by `didn't work out` ? Do you want the first character to be Visible and rest are `*` isn't it?

Comment: the code I posted did not work out. and yes, I want the first character/letter to be shown as a character/letter while the rest are shown as a asterisk/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the Following Example:

```
Dim inputString As String = "Password"
inputString = inputString(0) + New String("*", inputString.Length - 1)
```

In your case inputString should be replaced with `TextBox2.Text`; [Working Example Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oMCkBV)

Comment: @ChristianQuirante : Cool Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function

```
Friend Function FirstThenPass(ByVal Str As String) As String
    FirstThenPass = Mid(Str, 1, 1)
    For i = 1 To Str.Length - 1
        FirstThenPass &= "*"
    Next
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox2.Text.Length > 0 Then
        TextBox2.Text = FirstThenPass(TextBox2.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```